# Word 2010 VBA code to find, select and delete a table column with a specific column title

Tags: vba, ms-word

The scenario is a table is received each week in Word 2010 that needs adjustments. Among other additions to the macro, the column named "WebSite" needs to be deleted. **The column called "WebSite" might not always be in the same position though.**

I need to know the VBA code for finding, selecting and deleting a specific table column that can potentially change positions, but will always keep the same column title.

**Is there a way to insert a search word in the vba code that will ensure the right column is deleted even if its position in the table can change each time a table is opened in Word?**

Comment: `Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'
'
    Selection.SelectColumn
    Selection.Columns.Delete
End Sub` This is what shows when I do this using the Find feature in Word 2010 to find the keyword as the macro recorder is playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim tbl As Table
Dim cl As Cell

''All tables
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    ''Look in row 1 only ...
    For Each cl In tbl.Rows(1).Cells
        ''For a cell containing website and end of cell
        If cl.Range.Text = "website" & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
            ''Select ...
            cl.Column.Select
            ''Allow the user to choose delete
            If MsgBox("Del selected?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                cl.Column.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Very nice, can you provide an explanation as to the special characters that Word inserts to table cells? I've been wondering how to do a find and replace on words specifically in cells...